# When adding a faces message in JSF my actions aren't performed?

Tags: jsf-2

I have the following backing bean:

```
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean
public class WeighFamilyBacking2 implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String[] children = new String[] { "Child1", "Child2", "Child3" };
private HashMap<String, Integer> newWeights;

public WeighFamilyBacking2() {
    newWeights = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    for (String s : getChildren())
        newWeights.put(s, new Integer(0));
}

public void distributeWeightsWithoutMessage(ActionEvent event) {
    for (String s : newWeights.keySet()) {
        newWeights.put(s, newWeights.get(s) + 1);
    }
}

public void distributeWeights(ActionEvent event) {
    for (String s : newWeights.keySet()) {
        newWeights.put(s, newWeights.get(s) + 1);
    }

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,
            new FacesMessage("Succesful", "Weights redistributed."));
}

public HashMap<String, Integer> getNewWeights() {
    return newWeights;
}

public List<String> getChildren() {
    return Arrays.asList(children);
}
}
```

... And the following xhtml page:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <ui:repeat var="child" value="#{weighFamilyBacking2.children}">
            <h:outputText value="#{child}" />
            <h:outputText value="#{weighFamilyBacking2.newWeights[child]}" /> -
            <h:outputText value="#{weighFamilyBacking2.newWeights[child]}" /> - 
            <h:inputText id="oz" value="#{weighFamilyBacking2.newWeights[child]}" />
            <h:inputText id="lbs"
                value="#{weighFamilyBacking2.newWeights[child]}" />
            <br />
        </ui:repeat>

        <h:commandButton
            actionListener="#{weighFamilyBacking2.distributeWeights}"
            value="Redistribute" />


        <h:commandButton
            actionListener="#{weighFamilyBacking2.distributeWeightsWithoutMessage}"
            value="Redistribute Without Message" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

This is a simple reproducible test case. When you click on the redistribute without message, things work as expected. When you click on the redistribute button it displays the success message but the input fields are not updated. However, the text output field is updated just one time.

I have tried using immediate=true on both buttons and that doesn't affect this. This is a very simple case, I can't understand why it doesn't work.

I have tried this with all recent versions of Mojarra including 2.1.3.

Comment: What JSF impl/version? Cannot reproduce this issue with Mojarra 2.1.1.

Comment: I am using 2.1.2. I am also using richfaces 4 and primefaces is also in the mix. I'll try removing some of that and see if that helps.

Comment: Same results with just Mojarra 2.1.2 (FCS 20110610).

Comment: Ouch. Couldn't you cut out all irrelevant markup and template definitions into the smallest possible single and self-containing XHTML file which still reproduces the problem? Do some basic eliminating. Remove as much as possible components step by step and stop when the problem doesn't occur anymore and then go one step back.

Comment: BalusC -- I've made it as simple a repeatable test case as I can make it. Give it a try.. clicking button should increase all values +1 in the text and input fields. I appreciate your help!!! Thank you.

Comment: Great SSCCE. I can reproduce your problem. I bet that it's another `ui:repeat` anomaly again. I will look closer into this later the day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is another `<ui:repeat>` anomaly. I haven't nail down the exact root cause yet so that I can check if this is already reported to the [JSF guys](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES) and if necessary report it, but I can tell that it works when I replace the `<ui:repeat>` by a `<h:dataTable>`.

```xml
<h:dataTable var="child" value="#{weighFamilyBacking2.children}">
    <h:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{child}" />
        <h:outputText value="#{weighFamilyBacking2.newWeights[child]}" /> -
        <h:outputText value="#{weighFamilyBacking2.newWeights[child]}" /> - 
        <h:inputText id="oz" value="#{weighFamilyBacking2.newWeights[child]}" />
        <h:inputText id="lbs"
            value="#{weighFamilyBacking2.newWeights[child]}" />
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Maybe a `<table>` is not semantically correct for you. If this is really undesireable, you might want to check if it works without problems with Tomahawk's `<t:dataList>`, RichFaces' `<rich:dataList>`, PrimeFaces' `<p:dataList>`, etc each which supports rendering the children without additional markup.

**Update:** I  reported it as [issue 2157](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2157).

Comment: Thank you BalusC! At least I know I'm not crazy. A datatable would likely work fine here. Let me know if I should open up something with the JSF guys to report it. It's a fairly easy to reproduce to test case. It's strange that it only affects inputText elements within the repeat. I'm thinking maybe it has something to do with identifying the inputText elements within the repeat?

Comment: Yes, I've had a similar problem before with checkboxes in a nested `ui:repeat` which are been updated during invoke action. But there was no `FacesMessage` involved. I'm curious to the cause of the `FacesMessage` in your particuler issue.